# java program for Find MemberShip Category

Tags: java

ZEE Shopping mall wanted to know how many Members are available for each of their Membership category. The member ship category is of three types(Gold,Silver and Platinum). You need to implement a java program using thread to find out the count of members in each member ship category. MemberShip details should be obtained from the user in the console.

Create Member class with following private attributes

```
String memberId,

String memberName,

String category
```

Include appropriate getters and setters.

Write a three-argument constructor in the Member class with arguments – memberId, memberName, and category. And set the values via a constructor.

Create a class ZEEShop  that extends Thread with the following private attributes,

```
String memberCategory,

int count,

List<Member> memberList
```

Include appropriate getters and setters.

Write a two argument constructor in the ZEEShop class with arguments – memberCategory, and memberList. And set the values via constructor.

Invoke the ZEEShop thread class for each memberCategory and count the number of members in that category and display the count.

Write a two argument constructor in the ZEEShop with the memberCategory and memberList

Write the Main class and display the output as shown in the sample input/output

Assumption: The memberCategory is case –sensitive and will of only three values – Platinum,Gold,Silver

Sample Input and Output:

Enter the number of Members:
5
Enter the Member Details:

101:Tom:Gold

Enter the Member Details:

102:Sam:Gold

Enter the Member Details:

103:John:Silver

Enter the Member Details:

104:Rose:Platinum

Enter the Member Details:

105:Tint:Silver

Enter the number of times Membership category needs to be searched:
4
Enter the Category

Gold

Enter the Category

Silver

Enter the Category

Platinum

Enter the Category

Gold

Sample Output:

Gold:2
Silver:2
Platinum:1

Gold:2

Comment: you just posted a question without stating what you have done and what error you are getting?

Comment: I need java program

Comment: Note the following, which appears on this Web page: [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions) (1) It is okay to ask about homework. (2) Make a good faith attempt to solve the problem yourself first. (3) Ask about specific problems with your existing implementation.

Answer (score 0):

In main method get all your inputs using `Scanner` or `BufferedReader`. Once after getting your input do something like this in main method

```java
    List<ZEEShop> zList  = new ArrayList<ZEEShop>();
        for(int i=0;i<count;i++){
    //iterate and get inputs needed to invoke the method something like below
            ZEEShop zs = new ZEEShop(category, memList);
            zList.add(zs);
        }
    //loop thru list and start the threads

    for(ZEEShop z: zeelist){
        z.start();
        try {z.join();} catch (InterruptedException e) {e.printStackTrace();}
    }
```

In `ZEEShop.java` inside run method, write the logic to get count.
Hope this helps